# Prove that “No one likes Reggae music” is the same as “Everyone does not like Reggae music”.

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, alternative-proof

I interpreted this as a case of the extension of De Morgan's Law to quantifiers.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extensions

I know that similar questions have been asked before about a proof for De Morgan's Law for quantifiers, but this one is a bit different.

I couldn't find a proof for the quantifier-extension of De Morgan's Law that worked for a set of **any** cardinality so I have attempted to prove it using induction and I want to know if it is sound.

In the proof, I have denoted De Morgan's Law as DE and used it as a rule of inference. I also denoted *the act of liking Reggae music* as the function R(x)

[image: I had to use an image to avoid text being displayed incorrectly]

I had to use an image to avoid text being displayed incorrectly.
Also let me know if you know of a more elegant proof.

**Explanation of step 18**
I proved that De Morgan's Law could be used on an entire set with a cardinality of 3 (in step 9). Then I proved that if DE is done on an entire set with a cardinality of $n – 1$ (step 11), then DE could be done on a set with a cardinality of $n$. This is the requirements needed for induction, thus step 18 is valid.
Also take note of step 13.

Let me know if the proof is sound.

Comment: But what happens if your world has infinitely many people?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure my proof falls short if the cardinality is infinite. But it would be nice if someone could extend it to an infinite cardinality

Comment: [They don't like reggae ... they *love* it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hldoswNToxg)

Comment: Any two false statements are equivalent.

Comment: "I had to use an image to avoid text being displayed incorrectly." Do you know that in LaTeX math mode you can make regular text with `\text{}`?Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @alex.jordan no, I didn't know that. I am not very familiar with LaTeX. The actual problem I had was displaying the quantifiers correctly. (Especially lines 1 and 2 of the proof).

Comment: For instance, `{}_{\neg}\exists_{x\in A} R(x)\equiv\forall_{x\in A} {}_{\neg}R(x)` gives ${}_{\neg}\exists_{x\in A} R(x)\equiv\forall_{x\in A} {}_{\neg}R(x)$. You can tweak spacing as needed. The negations in subscript may not work for you either. Try without subscript.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that the clumsy statement "Everyone does not like Reggae music" in a normal English context is the same as the clearer "Not everyone likes Reggae music", which of course is not equivalent to "No one likes Reggae music". I admit there is some ambiguity about such usage, which is why it should be avoided.

Comment: To me as an English speaker, "Everyone does not like Reggae music" says that every single person doesn't like it, which is not how you are hearing it. So it might be better to say "in some English contexts" rather than "in a normal English context". We can only speak for our own regional linguistic nuances.